# Hide an element after another element loads? AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

So here's my code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
$(".post-link").click(function() {
  var post_link = $(this).attr("href");

  $("#single-post-container").html("content loading");
  $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
  return false;
});
$(".close-link").click(function() {
  jQuery("#single-post-container").css('display', 'none');

});
```

After the `#single-post-container` fully loads i want to hide an element.How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load()` accepts a function as a 2nd parameter, and it's a callback function to be executed after the load is complete.  Just add it there...

```
$("#single-post-container").load(post_link, function() {
    // hide the element here.
});
```

Comment: Yay worked finally... thanks! Didnt knew it was such a little thing :P

Comment: Yeah, jQuery is FULL of little things like that.  Their heavy use of callbacks made me totally rethink the way I wrote Javascript, and it's a lot better for it!  Glad I could help :)

Comment: there's one tiny error..the `#single-post-container` refreshes a few times if that same link clicked again

Comment: It should just do the exact same thing again.  Are you running the code that assigned the click handler more than once?

Comment: yes.. any other way and it messed up the code next to it.

Comment: That's your problem then.  There are various ways to handle that, but obviously running the code that assigns event handlers only once is the best way.  To safeguard an uncertain future, I use `$(".element").off("click").on("click", function() { });` which removes any existing click event handlers before assigning them.  This is overkill and is masking an error caused by something else, but it does work.

Comment: nah didnt work...when i went in the developer tools i saw the elements inside the #single-post-container were flashing like on and off when the .post-link was clicked for the second time

Comment: In that case you need to get to the root of that problem and fix it, rather than mask it like I suggested.  You should only ever assign event handlers once, unless you need to do it as I showed above.  In this case it sounds like you're running code repeatedly that should only run once.  Try to separate the event handler assignments from any other code.

Comment: Nah didnt work...works normally only if `$("#single-post-container").load(post_link, function() {
});` is removed..any other method?

Comment: Without seeing more of the script it's impossible to tell you what's wrong with it.  This specific issue *is* fixed with this answer, so you'd be better posting a new question with the relevant code.  Something's obviously wrong somewhere, but it won't be because of an AJAX call.

Comment: oh crap just realized that `var post_link` (its a link to a page) had the same script file which had this code..i removed the link to script in `var post_link` and works fine now yay! it seems like that whole script was repeating again in the `var post_link` which was causing errors..Thanks a ton lot for the support..

Comment: Ahhh.. that makes sense.  No worries - I'm glad you got it sorted :)